# 'this' binding in Reusable Functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope, this

I have put together a small script as part of a larger quiz project and am struggling to understand why the `this` keyword is being set in the function before it is called. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

     function nextCard() {
         console.log('yes');
         $(this).closest('.card').hide();
         $(this).parent().next().show();
     }

    $("#start").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //First card to appear
        nextCard();
    });

    $("#next").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        nextCard();
    });
});
```

Why would 'this' not be set to element #start for instance?

Comment: If you want `this` to be the element, you'd have to **reference** the function, as in `$("#next").on('click', nextCard)`

Comment: See my answer in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969) for how `this` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would 'this' not be set to element #start for instance?

Why would it be? It's not that it can *sense* what you want it to do.

Use [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to define what object `this` should point to during the call. If you don't explicitly define it, `this` will default to the global object (`Window` in browsers).

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    function nextCard() {
        console.log('yes');
        $(this).closest('.card').hide();
        $(this).parent().next().show();
    }

    $("#start").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //First card to appear
        nextCard.call(this);
    });

    $("#next").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        nextCard.call(this);
    });
});
```

Using `someFunction.call(this);` will effectively "transfer the current meaning" of `this` to the called function, or more technically, call `someFunction` in the context of whatever object `this` is referencing at the moment.

jQuery does something like the above automatically - it sets `this` for you to the proper DOM element when it calls event handlers. You can make use of the automatic `this` handling like [@Rory McCrossan's answer](http://@Rory%20McCrossan's%20answer%20shows.) shows – or you handle `this` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this and explanation

Comment: @dreamkiller It just so happens that I have written another take on the same subject today, read the lower part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210122/why-cant-promise-resolve-be-called-as-a-function/45210249#45210249 if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

Within `nextCard()`, `this` will refer to the `window` as that's the default scope. Hence your DOM traversal methods most likely are not working as you expect them to.

Assuming you want `this` within the function to refer to the clicked `#start` or `#next` element, you could provide the *reference* of `nextCard()` to the event handler methods, like this:

```js
$(function($) {
  function nextCard(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('yes');
    $(this).closest('.card').hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
  }

  $("#start, #next").on('click', nextCard);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but my intention is to add different functions within these two respective functions so can't have them within the same one

Comment: In that case you could split them: `$('#start').click(startCard);`, `$('#next').click(nextCard);`. I simply joined them in the answer to make it more succinct.

Comment: But my intention is to call the nextCard function within this click function and do other things. If I set the function to nextCard for both instead of function(e) {} then I won't be able to add anything further to these functions.

Comment: In which case you'd need to use `call()` to maintain scope, as @Tomalak pointed out

Comment: Thanks, did the job!