# two weird behavior of Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I found myself lack of understanding with `ES6 Promise`.

I have two questions

**Question 1)**

```
// clear

var _o = null

var m = () => {
    return new Promise(k => {
        _o = k
    })
}

m().then(r => {console.log(r+1000)})

_o(100)

// 1100
```

As you've seen above, when `_o` is called with its value, promise resolves, and we can log the value (thanks to .then)

So the above example looks very clear.

But here is an example that I cannot fully understand.

```
// weird 

var _o = null

var test = () => {
    return new Promise(res => {
        _o = res
    })
}

test();

var p = _o(100)

console.log(p) // undefined
```

How can `p` be undefined?

According to the [promise mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#:%7E:text=resolve()%20method%20returns%20a,resolved%20with%20a%20given%20value.),

> The Promise.resolve() method returns a Promise object that is resolved
> with a given value.

I thought that `p` has to be resolved Promise object.

**Question 2)**

```
Promise.resolve(10).then(r => console.log(r))  // 10


var p = Promise.resolve

p(10).then(r => console.log(r))

// Uncaught TypeError: PromiseResolve called on non-object
```

why does that `p(10)` fires an error?

I already referenced this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210122/why-cant-promise-resolve-be-called-as-a-function/45210249), but still failed to fully understand.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can p be undefined?

You seem to make the assumption that `Promise.resolve` (which you quote) is the same as the function that gets passed into the `Promise` constructor callback. They are not the same:

```js
new Promise(resolve => {
   console.log(Promise.resolve === resolve);
})
```

In fact, the specification defines that the passed in function returns `undefined`: [25.6.1.3.2 Promise Resolve Functions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions).

You can think of `Promise.resolve` being equivalent to

```js
Promise.resolve = function (value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(value));
}
```

---

> why does that p(10) fires an error?

This is only partly related to `Promise`. It generally is due how `this` inside functions work. From [the specification about `Promise.resolve`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-promise.resolve):

> The `resolve` function expects its `this` value to be a constructor function that supports the parameter conventions of the Promise constructor.

If you call the function as `p(...)` then `this` is `undefined`.

If the function is called as `Promise.resolve(...)` then its `this` value will refer to `Promise`.

It's not uncommon for builtin functions to expect their `this` value to be a specific kind of object/value.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks! *"Built-in functions that are ECMAScript function objects must be strict functions."* https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects

Comment: Very helpful. Appreciate for your help!

Comment: @Bergi I have further question regards to the first question. If p returns undefined, then how .then knows whether the promise has been resolved?

Comment: @jwkoo The `resolve()` call *tells* the promise to become resolved.

Comment: @Bergi The resolve() call returns undefined, but set flag to true so that .then to be chained for example?

Comment: @jwkoo It returns `undefined`, but schedules the callbacks that the `then()` calls registered on the promise. And it sets an internal flag, yes.

Comment: @Bergi totally understood. Thank you!